# How do I re-route SSH connection depending on incoming address?

Tags: networking, server, ssh

Recently, I was tasked with the problem that I needed to re-route an incoming connection to a specific user depending on their public IP address...

For example, let's say that Bob runs:

```
ssh nerd@server_ip
```

how could I re-route him(123.123.123.123 in this example) so that instead of logging in as `nerd`, he logs in as `admin`?

#### What I've tried

I've tried different configurations and combinations with `MatchAddress` and `MatchUser`... I've also tried using a script with `ForceCommand` in SSH...

#### More Clarification

To clarify futher, I want to re-route Bob in the previous example to the user "admin" because of his IP address (123.123.123.123). But if another person, let's say Julia was to run `ssh nerd@server_ip`, it would re-route her to `non-admin@server_ip` because her IP was (1.1.1.1)...

Answer (score 0):

## Client side

I do not think that this is possible to do as part of the ssh server configuration. The "Match" option does not allow the "User" directive to be used with it in order to force a different user account than the one requested.

However you could give Bob and Julia advice on how to configure this in their own `~/.ssh/config`. For instance tell Bob to add the following to this file:

```
Host server_ip
    User admin
```

And Julia should add:

```
Host server_ip
    User non-admin
```

Now if they add this configuration on their client hosts 123.123.123.123 or 1.1.1.1 this would make them able to just run

```
ssh server_ip
```

and the ssh client will use admin or non-admin as the user part of the connection, depending on the client where it is executed.

This is for sure not exactly what you are asking for, but I guess the closest you can get using ssh.

## Use authorized_keys

Depending on what Bob and Julia need to do on the server, you could also make them use public keys for authentication and hard code a given command into the authorized_keys file. The advantage of this is that in the authorized_keys file you can require a certain "from" address and force a certain command to be executed. See the "AUTHORIZED_KEYS FILE FORMAT" section in the sshd(8) manual page. Still, this will only allow you to restrict a certain public key to be used from a certain address, it will not do any rerouting of the connection to another account, as you originally asked.